# How to convert Array PHP to js then back to PHP to insert into SQL

Tags: javascript, php, input

i need some help.

User will input data on the box which can be increased.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ref_title[]">
```

so the data `ref_title` will have multiple entries which are all stored in an array.

this works for a normal input.

```
var lvl = $('#lvl'+str).val();
```

However, how do i pass it in js?

Comment: Why do you tag Java and PHP both?

Comment: @TaReQMahMooD Probably because OP thinks java == javascript

Comment: Is this for an AJAX call? Why do you need this in JS?

Comment: This question is incoherent, at least to me.  What does "User will input data on the box which can be increased." mean?  How does this have something to do with ref_title, which is an id tag, having multiple entries?  Multiple titles in the same string for one id?  Its unclear.